# How to setup django logging to console

Tags: django, logging

I know there is a very similar question. That one is six years old and the answer in that one doesn't help me. All I want is to know how to configure django so that it can log to the console.

This are my settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

And in my view I have this:

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "inicio/magic_py.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger("django")
        logger.debug("home!!!!!!")
        print("home?")
```

The console doesn't show the log.debug, it only shows the print. What am I missing? please help.

I use django 1.10

Comment: You have log level `'INFO'` in your loggers dict.  Try `'DEBUG'` if you want to see debug level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEBUG log level is lower than INFO so your logs are being filtered out, you'll need to either lower your log level to DEBUG or you need to log using logger.info() or higher.